# egit not pulling with submodulus eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I am working on a project that has submodules in it. In order to update the project to the latest version I need to use the next commands : `git pull` and `git submodule update`.

I have start using eclipse with [EGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/). the problem is when I am doing pull through the eclipse interface it doesn't updates the submodules as well. How do I update submodules of a project from within eclipse ?